# After creating a role with grant update user1.table1, I gave grant role to user2, when executing the update I received Error ORA-01031

Tags: sql, oracle

After creating role RL_WRITE and granting the grant update to table user1.table1 to role and granting role to user2 I get insufficient privileges error.

```
CREATE ROLE RL_WRITE;

GRANT UPDATE ON user1.table1 TO RL_WRITE;

GRANT RL_WRITE to user2;
```

logged in as user2, when running the command:

```
update user1.table1 set datmov = to_date('18/10/21','dd/mm/yy');
```

```
*01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges*
```

I don't understand what might be missing.

Comment: Is there a trigger on table1? Did you login as user2 _after_ the role grant was made?

Comment: This table has no trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. `User user2` already had the role `RL_READ_ONLY` and I created the `RL_WRITE` and then grant it to `user2`.

But that `user2` was set as `ALTER USER user2 DEFAULT ROLE RL_READ_ONLY` and so, even after having made the `GRANT UPDATE ON user1.table1 TO RL_WRITE` for the role, and granted this role to `user2` the update command did not work.

**SOLUTION**

Only After doing the command `ALTER USER user2 DEFAULT ROLE ALL;`  That `user2` was able to make the updates, inserts and deletes commands that the role `RL_WRITE` had already had permission.

Answer (score 0):

GRANT **SELECT**, UPDATE ON user1.table1 TO RL_WRITE;

Comment: In fact I had already granted GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON user1.table1 TO RL_WRITE; And yet the same error remains

Comment: Can user2 SELECT from user1.table1?

Comment: Yes, user2 can select on user1.table1 table.

Comment: I did a test I GRANT UPDATE ANY TABLE TO USER2, and the update worked, but when I removed the grant GRANT UPDATE ANY TABLE from user2 and granted the same grant to role RL_WRITE the permission update any table does not work.

Comment: Permissions granted to a role are *not* available to users who have been granted that role *until* such users disconnect and then re-connect their sessions.